# OCL collection operation on list attribute

Tags: class, collections, uml, software-design, ocl

I'm modelling a problem in which there are **students** and **courses**.
Each courses have some other courses as prerequisites and I want to make an OCL constraint on the "joinCourse()" operation of students to allow them to join a courses if and only if they have finished required courses.

this is a draft of the UML class diagram I made:
[image]

now, my **question** is:
is possible to make a **collection operation**, like "includeAll" on a **"list attribute"** like finishedCourses?

I made this ocl constraint:

```
context Student::joinCourse(c: Course)
pre: self.finishedCourses->includesAll(c.requiredCourses)
```

correct?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately your "blueprint" (class diagram ?) is not visible since the url provided in your question requires a registration.  Could you share it in another way ?

Comment: I suggest you use an OCL evaluator such as the Eclipse OCL Interactive Xtext OCL Console to practice your OCL evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes, it's correct.

### Justification

In the [UML 2.5 specifications](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/About-UML/) there is a clear link between multiplicity and collection:

> 7.5.3.2. A MultiplicityElement is an Element that may be instantiated in some way to represent a collection of values. (...)

The [OCL specification](https://www.omg.org/spec/OCL/2.3.1/) explains how self relates to the context (clause 7.3.4):

> The OCL expression can be part of a Precondition or Postcondition,
>   corresponding to «precondition» and «postcondition» stereotypes of
>   Constraint associated with an Operation or other behavioral feature.
>   The contextual instance self then is an instance of the type that owns
>   the operation or method as a feature.

So in your expression, `self` refers to a `Student`, and a dot allows to access its properties, such as  self.finishedCourse refers to a collection property.

OCL defines collection types (clause 11.6) and general operations that are well formed for all collections (clause 11.7.1):

> `includesAll(c2 : Collection(T)) : Boolean` 
>   Does self contain all the elements of `c2` ? 
>   post: `result = c2->forAll(elem | self->includes(elem))`

So `self.finishedCourses->includesAll(c.requiredCourses)` is a valid expression that is true or false exactly in the situation that you expect.

### Additional remark

A property may represent an attribute of a classifier or a member end of an association. You could have represented `finishedCourse` as the end of a second association between `Student` and `Course` (being understood that all courses taken are not necessarily finished).